# How to test youtube live streaming API SuperChatEvents features?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm building a pretty large app via youtube live streaming API.
But, there is no way to test SuperChatEvents API.

If I want to test SuperChatEvents API, should I make an account that can be monetized? or Does Youtube support super chat test mode?